# Should I declare a 'nonisolated' or 'async' function in my 'MainActor' view model for work that will run inside and outside of the MainActor context?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-concurrency

## Intro

I have a view model declared as follows:

```swift
@MainActor class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    ...
}
```

I want to add a function to this model which does a mixture of work inside and outside of the [MainActor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mainactor) context.

I've run some experiments and I've come up with two options which achieve this, as described below.

### Option 1

Mark the new function in the view model as `nonisolated` and initiate a [Task](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task) within the function, as follows:

```swift
nonisolated func someFunction() {
    Task {
        // Do work here.
        // Use 'await' to make calls to the 'MainActor' context
        // and to make other asynchronous calls.
    }
}
```

Call on this function in the View as follows:

```swift
Button("Execute") {
    viewModel.someFunction()
}
```

### Option 2

Mark the new function in the view model as `async` and omit the [Task](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task) initiation, as follows:

```swift
func someFunction() async {
    // Do work here.
    // No need to 'await' to make calls to the 'MainActor' context
    // given that this function runs in the 'MainActor' context.
    // Use 'await' to make asynchronous calls
    // and to free up the 'MainActor' whilst those calls execute.
}
```

Call on this function in the View as follows:

```swift
Button("Execute") {
    Task {
        await viewModel.someFunction()
    }
}
```

## The Question

Do either of the two options above have advantages over the over or are they both functionally the same? Is there an alternative option which is more idiomatic to Swift and SwiftUI, and offers advantages over the two options above?

## Update

When I asked this question initially, I was under the impression that I had to use `await` to make calls to the `MainActor` context from `someFunction()` in Option 2 above. That is incorrect.

I have edited the comment in the code block in Option 2 to remove this incorrect assumption so that I do not mislead anyone in future who stumbles across this question.

Comment: Neither is a good option. That is the purpose of Task.detached. Floating tasks that you don’t hold on to will end up leaking use .task to run async func

Comment: In order to better advise you, we really need to see a practical example of what `someFunction` is actually doing.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers thus far  I will mull your answers and come back and improve my question next Friday. I realise from your answers that there are one or two specifics about my problem that I need to call out and make explicit. Bear with me.

Comment: @AdilHussain fyi in SwiftUI the View structs is your view model and you can use .task for async and await funcs declared outside View structs to run on background threads or in custom actors, eg task(id: isExecuting) and set isExecuting true in a button.

Comment: @AdilHussain - Needless to say, the use of MVVM is entirely a matter of personal opinion and you should do what you want. The use of MVVM is not relevant to the question at hand.

Comment: I updated my question ever-so-slightly and added an **Update** section to call out what I changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In answer to the question regarding how to get this off the current actor, there are a variety of approaches:

- move it into its own `actor` … this is preferrable if there is some shared mutable state or need to prevent parallel execution resulting from multiple calls, but is possibly overkill if the intent is just to get a single function off the main actor;
- have it launch a `detached` task … this is a simple way to get work off the current actor, but entails [unstructured concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency#Unstructured-Concurrency), encumbering the author with the burden of manual cancelation handling, etc.; or
- make it a non-isolated `async` function, as discussed in [SE-0338](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0338-clarify-execution-non-actor-async.md) … this keeps us within the realm of [structured concurrency](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0304-structured-concurrency.md) and the benefits that confers, while getting us off the current actor.

---

This begs the question as to whether you need to get `someFunction` off the main actor at all. The fact that this function will subsequently “make calls to the `MainActor`” suggests that you should keep this function on the main actor, too.

So, there are a few considerations regarding ensuring that `someFunction` never blocks the main actor:

1. If this code will simply `await` other `async` methods, then there is no concern about blocking the main thread/actor. As soon the task encounters an `await` suspension point, the current task is suspended, but the current actor (i.e., the main actor) is freed to perform other tasks while the asynchronous code runs. The current thread/actor will not be blocked.

   For example, consider the following:

   ```swift
   func someFunction() async {
       let response = await someThingElse()   // this is asynchronous and will not block
       self.objects = results.objects         // now update property isolated to the main actor with no `await`
   }
   ```

   If you `await` other `async` methods, it now becomes immaterial that `someFunction` happens to be isolated to the main actor or not. As soon as `someFunction` encounters an `await` suspension point, the current actor is freed to do other tasks while the asynchronous work is underway. As you can see, if `someFunction` later needs to do something on the main actor, this makes its intent clear and simplifies your code.
2. If `someFunction` performs any slow and synchronous work (e.g., file i/o, etc.) before continuing to do more on the main actor, then move that synchronous work (and only that work) into its own function. You can get this new function off the main actor (e.g., a non-isolated `async` function, a detached task, its own actor, whatever). But once this new function with the synchronous code is off the main actor, you can then keep `someFunction` on the main actor, `await` its call to this new function. This simplifies `someFunction`, making its intent clear (that it will use the main actor at some point), but gets the slow and synchronous work off the main actor.

   With this pattern, again, the main actor will not be blocked and only the slow, synchronous code is moved off the current actor.

---

As an aside, I would avoid unnecessarily introducing [unstructured concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency#Unstructured-Concurrency) with `Task {…}`. With unstructured concurrency, you bear all responsibility for handling task cancellation. For example , note that if you discard the resulting task reference, as you have in option 1, it “makes it impossible for you to explicitly cancel the task.” Properly handling cancelation with `Task {…}` requires extra work; if you remain within structured concurrency, you get these behaviors for free. Avoid unstructured concurrency, if you can.

I would also suggest that you also avoid introducing detached tasks, too, unless absolutely necessary, as that also introduces unstructured concurrency. As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/detached(priority:operation:)-3lvix) says:

> Don’t use a detached task if it’s possible to model the operation using structured concurrency features like child tasks. Child tasks inherit the parent task’s priority and task-local storage, and canceling a parent task automatically cancels all of its child tasks. You need to handle these considerations manually with a detached task.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer and capturing all the different nuances to consider when choosing one option over another, e.g. are there any slow synchronous calls being made in `someFunction()` or are all slow calls made with `await`.

Comment: Regarding your advice against unnecessarily introducing unstructured concurrency with `Task {…}`: Am I right in saying that I have to initialise a [Task](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task) or use the [task(id:priority:action:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(id:priority:_:)) function to make a call into an `async` function from a SwiftUI or UIKit view? I can't see any way around this.

Comment: In SwiftUI, where it is appropriate to launch it when the view is presented, definitely prefer the `.task` view modifier. The beauty is that when the view is dismissed, the asynchronous task will be automatically canceled for you (assuming you didn't unnecessarily introduce some unmanaged, unstructured concurrency). And, sure, if you have a `Button` that is launching an asynchronous task, you’ll have to launch it via `Task {…}`, like your “option 2”, as that’s how you bridge from the button action’s synchronous context to an asynchronous one).

Comment: … But avoid writing synchronous functions like your “option 1” that introduce unstructured concurrency, because you are starting a `Task {…}`, throwing away its reference, and now have no way of ever canceling it. Sure, right now you are not contemplating canceling what you've started with the button, but should you ever want to do that, you don't want to have to go back and refactor your `async` code. This is why Apple repeated tells us to avoid unstructured concurrency where it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add a function to this model which does a mixture of work inside and outside of the MainActor context.

If the goal / problem is to guarantee that certain code runs not on the main actor, then all your code is wide off the mark. Instead, you need to make *a different actor*. That is (in part) what actors are for.

Comment: My understanding of actors is that they exist to coordinate access to shared data a bit like a serial queue but with added compiler safety. With all due respect to you, I'm not convinced that moving code to a custom actor for the sake of ensuring that it does not run on the MainActor context is the right thing to do. In doing so, I would be adding an extra constraint to the code which I may not require. Specifically, the code will only will be able to run in one task at any given time.

Comment: An actor is _exactly_ how you say in async/await that code is to be run not on the main actor. I know, it takes getting used to. Moreover, an actor is re-entrant during any `await` calls it may make; this is how it straightens out access to its state. As long as the actor itself does not have added code that strictly serializes, it does _not_ prevent multiple calls into itself at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

## Evaluating the options

After pondering [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1271826/rob)'s answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76887492/1071320)) and continuing to experiment with [Swift Concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency/), my position now is that we should initiate the [Task](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task) in the view (outside of the view model).<sup>1</sup> The question then becomes whether we should define the functions in our [MainActor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mainactor) view models:

1. With the `async` keyword only;
2. With the `nonisolated` keyword only;
3. With the `nonisolated` and `async` keywords; or
4. Without the `nonisolated` and `async` keywords.

Let's go through each option one by one and discuss when it applies.

### Option 1 – Declare the function with the async keyword only

Declare the function in your view model with the `async` keyword only (i.e. without the `nonisolated` keyword) if it makes any calls that require an `await` and it makes no longstanding blocking calls<sup>2</sup>.

### Option 2 – Declare the function with the nonisolated keyword only

Declare the function in your view model with the `nonisolated` keyword only (i.e. without the `async` keyword) if (1) it does not access any methods or properties isolated to the view model, (2) it makes no calls that require an `await` and (3) it makes no longstanding blocking calls.<sup>3</sup>

### Option 3 – Declare the function with the nonisolated and async keywords

Declare the function in your view model with both the `async` and `nonisolated` keywords if it makes longstanding blocking calls.

### Option 4 – Declare the function without the nonisolated and async keywords

Declare the function in your view model without the `async` and `nonisolated` keywords if it makes no calls that require an `await` and it makes no longstanding blocking calls.<sup>3</sup>

## Summary

Whether you declare a function in your [MainActor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mainactor) view model as `nonisolated` or `async` or both or neither depends on what exactly you're doing in your function. Here's a digest of the preceding discussion:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | **no calls that require 'await'** | **1+ calls that require 'await'** |
| **no longstanding blocking calls** | declare without `async` and `nonisolated` keywords | declare with `async` keyword only |
| **1+ longstanding blocking calls** | declare with both `nonisolated` and `async` keywords | declare with both `nonisolated` and `async` keywords |

See [this sample application](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/SwiftUI-experiments/tree/master/App6) for a concrete example of each of the options.

## Footnotes

<sup><sup>1</sup>This is so that your code enters into structured concurrency at the earliest point possible.

<sup>2</sup>By "longstanding blocking call" I mean a function that blocks the thread that it is called on for more than a few milliseconds.

<sup>3</sup>If your function meets these conditions, you don't actually need to initiate a Task in your view to call it from.</sup>